Deploy azure container app from VisualStudio - Error 404
I'm trying to deploy the Asp.net Web API template in an azure container app.
The deploy finish with successful but when i navigate the Url it return 404 error.
I've enabled External traffic but still not working, missing something?
It tell that it only work if in enviroment the property internal is set to false.
But i can't find that property


What error you are getting?

Classic error 404 not reachable

try adding path /weatherforecast after the url. if you are using VS template of web API. because that is the path where page is hosted

I created a ASP.NET Core Web API VS template and Deployed to Container apps.
This is my project structure:

Default Dockerfile:
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication1"
RUN dotnet build "./WebApplication1.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./WebApplication1.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]

This is my configuration of the Container App.

OUTPUT:
It is throwing 404 error on the Url because API is not hosted on the home('/') path.

API is hosted on path /weatherforecast.

EDIT: Adding swagger file
To add swagger you need to add these code in you Program.cs
swagger.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API 1"); it will generate a swagger file based on the router/contoller/model used in project to render the swagger UI when web API is build.
app.Environment.IsProduction() is added for production environment like Azure or any other cloud services.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()|| app.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(swagger =>
    {
        swagger.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API 1");
    });
}

It is accessible at path /swagger/index.html


Im using swagger, so i tryed to add /swagger/index.html but still 404

@MatteoBeretta I have updated my answer based on your requirement to use swagger file.

Thank you, i fell so dumb, i was focusing on a network problem

I am glad it helped you
